# How can I set an universal working directory?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm setting up a new algorithm and I want to share it on another computer. How can I set paths with only the folder name, for example.

I've tried to use the function os.chdir(path), but I don't achieve to reach my folder when I'm not using a 'root path' like C:/../../folder.

```py
os.chdir(../folder_name)
```

Comment: If you only have the folder name, how do you know where that folder is (regardless of the Python code to get there)?  What if there are multiple folders with that name?

Comment: The fact is that I want to create a 'portable folder' which be can shared. I search a way which allows me to launch all my modules and functions on another computer. And by using 'root' path, I can't because it refers to my user name.

Comment: That's nice, but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `os.chdir(../folder_name)`, you are referring to the parent dir of the current directory.

You probably are looking for the `os.chdir(./folder_name)`, with one dot? This is the current directory, where your script stands.

> More here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats

**Update**: After clarification in the comments, you want to refer to `folder_name` from one of its subfolder (`/folder_name/library`). Then it is indeed `..` that you should use, but `..` **only**:

```
os.chdir(..)
```

Comment: Thanks but when I'm using this syntax: `os.chdir('./folder_name')`, this error appears: `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`. I'll search further information about that but thanks for your answer!

Comment: Is there a folder names `folder_name` in the same directory that your python script?

Comment: No, I put all my scripts in `/folder_name/library`. In fact, this destination is my working directory and I search a way to universalize this path.

Comment: It actually works! Just to clarity a point, the fact to use `os.chdir("..")` allows to go back to subfolder where the script is executed, and set it as the working directory? (I hope this is the right answer)

Comment: `os.chdir("..")` change the working directory to be the **parent folder** of the one's where your script is located (i.e. `/folder_name/library`).